# Weird error on zuul gateway with microservices Url not found

Tags: microservices, http-status-code-404, netflix-zuul, gateway

im trying to  implement configuration with zuul gateway to centralize mi requests but eventually zuul url and prefix are not recognized.
I already have closed the project, and rebuilt it , but still keeps the same .

Lets say i got Eureka , Zuul , and one of my microsrvices is products

Then my Eureka configuration would be like :

```
EUREKA APPLICATION

package com.microeureka;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroeurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroeurekaApplication.class, args);
    }

}

EUREKA APP PROPERTIES


spring.application.name=micro-eureka-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch=false
```

Then one of my microservices, in this case Products has this cponfiguration on app.properties

```
#CONEXION CONVENCIONAL
----------------------

#nombre de la aplicacion
spring.application.name=micro-products

#conexion a la base  SQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:xxxxxx/xxxxxx?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

#datos de acceso a la base de datos
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx

#driver de acceso a la base de datos
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug


server.port=${PORT:0}


eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

and its POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microproducts</groupId>
    <artifactId>microproducts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microproducts</name>
    <description>Demo project for microproducts</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--LIBRERIA COMUN DE COMMONS CREADA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SWAGGER 2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SWAGGER UI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SPRING REST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SPRING WEB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       

        <!--        EUREKA CLIENT-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
                </dependency>

       

        <!--        GATEWAY ZUUL-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
                </dependency>

       <!--DEVTOOLS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        
        <!--        CONNEXION A MYSQL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

thus then last but not leats the zuul configuration would be as follows:
first the Spring application class:

```
package com.microzuul;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicrozuulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicrozuulApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

then the application.properties configuration with its conexion to the microservice products:

```
spring.application.name=micro-zuul-server

server.port=9001


eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

zuul.routes.serviceProductsRoute.service-id=micro-products
zuul.routes.serviceProductsRoute.path=/zuul/products/**




hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds:60000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout:9000
ribbon.ReadTimeout:30000
```

And lets say my controller of products has an endpoint like `/product/list` bringing all products
thus once all this is canalized through zuul would be something like

```
http://localhost:9001/zuul/products/product/list
```

but for some reason on my postman i receive a 404 response
as :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-26T22:44:06.507+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/zuul/products/product/list"
}
```

my pom in zuul is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microzuul</groupId>
    <artifactId>microzuul</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microzuul</name>
    <description>Demo project for microzuul</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--        REST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

 
        <!--        EUREKA CLIENT-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        HYSTRIX-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        ZUUL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--        DEVTOOLS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--        TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any idea about why this behave .thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Might be silly but apparently zuul on first word as prefix in zuul application.properties is banned.
Just Changiing the world , or adding something first , did the work.

instead of

```
zuul.routes.serviceProductsRoute.path=/zuul/products/**
```

i used:

```
zuul.routes.serviceProductsRoute.path=/something else here (not the word zuul)/products/**
```